# The <title> tag becomes empty on my homepage

Tags: php, symfony1, apache2, symfony-1.4

I'm having some weird problem with my `<title>` tag on my homepage (the problem occurs only on this page). The title does appear and after some refresh disappear (meaning I have `<title>Homepage</title>` and then `<title></title>`)

The problem occurs only on my production server. There's no problem on dev servers.

The problem seems to be resolved if I do create another configuration mode. For instance, I tried with my `bypassmode.php` (a copy from `index.php` but with new values: `prod` => `bypass` in my `app.yml` & `doctrine.yml`).

When I edit on production the `view.yml` to change title and then I `./symfony cc`, it works again but disappear after a refresh. Same as when I do add the `$response->setTitle('Homepage');` directly in the action.

I've taken a look at the cache file `./cache/frontend/prod/config/modules_home_config_view.yml.php` but the title is set correctly.

I'm running out of ideas... Any suggestions ?

EDIT: As suggested below, I moved my `<title>` the closest possible to the `<head>` but it did not change anything.

After further investigation in `function include_title()`, is it possible that sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->getTitle(); might be undefined ? May APC be a problem ?

I'm considering editing `AssetHelper.php`:

```
function include_title()
{
  $title = sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->getTitle();

  // Adding some ugly patch here
  if (empty($title))
      $title = "Default title for my homepage";
  // End nasty patch

  echo content_tag('title', $title)."\n";
}
```

But this is so dirty that I wish I can find any other cleaner solution...

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a normal question in which the asker elaborates enough on the context/error/etc.

Comment: Why don't you use slots? Define a slot on your homepage named `title` with a default value, i,e `<title><?php include_slot('title', 'Default Title') ?></title>` and then whenever you want to change it, in your template `<?php slot('title', 'New Title!')); ?>`

Comment: But many of my titles are defined in my view.yml so I would have to move all of them into controllers, right ?

Comment: Not into controllers, just inside the view (templates). Also, could you please post a sample of your `view.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

The main cause for this is if you're using HTTP/1.1 and the Transfer-Encoding is chunked. If the `<title>` tag is not one of the very first things in the `<head>`, the chunking may cause the browser to get lost.

Try moving the `<title>` tag closer to the top of the `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I didn't know about that. I tried your solution but unfortunately, it didn't change anything.